# How to produce simulation results using batch for different configuration in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

I have an .ini file with [General] where common parameters are specified, then two sections [Config X] and [Config Y] where parameters corresponding to X, Y parameters are specified respectively. I want to generate simulation results for the two different configuration using CmdEnv. But when I run I just got results for general section. How can I achieve this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the config name on the command line

```
$ ./mysim -u Cmdenv -c X
```

if you do not specify the config name, by default general is executed.